# dnn how to uniquely identify instances of the same module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am currently building a page that is supposed to have multiple instances of the same DNN module but I'm having trouble uniquely identifying each instance. I thought the `ModuleId` property would do the trick but further research revealed that `ModuleId` is shared across all instances of that module. Does anyone know of a way to uniquely identify **each instance** of a DNN module?

Answer (score 0):

Try using TabModuleId instead, though ModuleId is shared across all "copies" of a module, not all instances of a module.

If you were to add a module to a Page A (via the control panel), then add the same module to that same page (via the control panel), you would get a new ModuleID and a new TabModuleId

If you were to COPY a module to another page (via the control panel add existing), choosing the modules on the first page. The ModuleId of the two modules would be the same, but the TabModuleIds would be unique.

Comment: OK but even so, I'm having trouble uniquely identifying modules on a page and I've tried `TabId`, `TabModuleId` and `ModuleId` all to no avail. My end goal is to have a bunch of the same module instances on a single page, all of which I can uniquely identify; is there a way to do this?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more detail because what I explained is how DNN works, and how to uniquely identify

Comment: I have a bunch of grids (which I have made modules out of) that I want to be able to display on one page. I want to specify their datasources (which will all be different from one another) using their identifiers. I have tried what you suggested above and none of those techniques/properties provide me with a unique way to identify each instance of the module. When I add the first grid to the page, it has ModuleId = 429. When I add the second one, both have ModuleId = 430 etc... when I want the first to maintain ModuleId = 429 and the second one to have the new ModuleId = 430.